# ConnectionMultiplexer.cs not found

Tags: c#, azure, redis

I'm trying to set up a project to learn about azure redis cache.
when i've tried to debug i got a message "ConnectionMultiplexer.cs not found".
I can't find the file in my machine either.

I have the StackExchange.Redis package installed already and the guide I followed is here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache/

I can't post an image but when i come to the line
 `ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("contoso5.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=true,password=...");`

and hit F11 the "Source Not Found" tab on visual studio comes up and it says that ConnectionMultiplexer.cs not found.

Comment: Please can you be specific about what code is requesting `ConnectionMultiplexer.cs` ? Because the library ([`StackExchange.Redis`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/)) is distributed *as a nuget package*, and as a dll. Are you sure that is the exact verbatim error message? To be specific: `ConnectionMultiplexer` is a *type* from the package, but you don't need a `ConnectionMultiplexer.cs` **file**.

Comment: This happens to me even if I don't hit F11. It makes debugging a nightmare. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is this because you tried to view the source code of `ConnectionMultiplexer` by pressing F11 but you don't have. Since you added `StackExchange.Redis` through NuGet the source code or PDB is not included.

If you do want to debug into the source of `ConnectionMultiplexer` you can download the source from its GitHub repository, add the project(s) into your solution and reference them as a project reference instead of using NuGet.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks! i tried to debug without going to that line and it work.

Comment: @Shaun I have come across the same problem when debugging but don't understand what am supposed to do? Do you mean to download this source https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs and then what? Or is it that there is a problem with my EntityFramework  reference?